# (C#) How to get the point to pixel relationship for my screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, gdi+

From what I've understood the relationship point to pixel will depend on the screen resolution. So how can I calculate it at run-time in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to get the DPI of the screen it's a bit trickier. You'll have to create a real Graphics object and query that.

For example, in the Load event of your main form:

```
using( Graphics g = CreateGraphics() )
{
    _dpiX = g.DpiX;
    _dpiY = g.DpiY; // In practice usually == dpiX
    _points = _dpiX / 72.0f; // There are 72 points per inch
}
```

Of course most monitors lie about the actual DPI and always return 72 or 96, or when large fonts are enabled 120. If you actually want to map a physical inch to a the screen you'll have to actually calibrate it with the user's help - having them pick a line that they measure to be 1 inch.

Comment: I got all the way to `_points`. Now, how would I relate `_points` to `pixels`?

Answer (score -1):

It is all in the **Screen** object:

```
int bpp = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.BitsPerPixel;
int wid = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width;
int ht = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height;
```

On my machine it gives:

```
bpp=32
width=1280
height=740
```

Comment: When working with the Screen object always keep in mind that some users are working with multiple monitors. Somewhere there is a function which returns the screen on which you application is visible at the moment.

Comment: How does the working area translate to DPI and therefore Points?

Comment: I don't see a relation of Points vs Pixels (DPI) pointed out in this comment, so I voted this answer down and will correct it once the answer is updated. I also have the same problem and cannot figure out how to do it - except using Graphics.